# Как проверить, начинается ли слово на согласную букву латинского алфавита? C++

Tags: c++

Допустим у нас есть набор слов, который записан в одномерный массив.

```
int n;
cout << "Введите кол-во слов = ";
cin >> n;

string* words = new string[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    cout << "Введите " << i + 1 << " слово: ";
    cin >> words[i];
}
```

Как проверить, начинается ли слово с согласной буквы латинского алфавита?

Comment: Ну а как Вы бы это в голове или на листочке делали?

Comment: все еще думаю... я со строчными элементами мало работал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isconsonant(char ch)
{
    static std::string consonants("bcdfghjklmnpqrstwvxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTWVXZ");
    return consonants.find(ch) != std::string::npos;
}

int main()
{
    std::string words[3];
    system("chcp 1251");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Введите " << i + 1 << " слово: ";
        std::cin >> words[i];
        if (words[i].length() > 0 && isconsonant(words[i][0]))
        {
            std::cout << "Первая буква слова согласная" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ой ой. `system("chcp 1251")` - это раз, `words[i].length() >0` - это два, `static` ненужный (где наверно лучше `const` было бы) - три.

Comment: ок, я привожу пример, по дефолту VS юзает для констант 1251 на винде. если менять кодировку будет нечитаемые надписи. объяснять как сменить кодировку в файле или консоли не входит в тему вопроса, а другим ищущим ответ будет проще воспроизвести конечный пример с дефолтными настройками. вариант на linux будет прекрасно работать также. т.к. там везде UTF-8 и так все нормально, и system() не повлияет на конечный результат.

Comment: words[i].length() >0 просто привычка. в данном случае оно может быть и не надо, но положим мы перенесли код в другое место и уже не сможем с уверенностью сказать, что обращение к пустой строке по нулевому индексу не вызовет исключение, правда?

Comment: static нужно чтобы при повторном вызове функции переменная не инициализировалась каждый раз. думаю компилятор и так возможно поймет что она должна быть постоянно хранимой в памяти, но это тоже привычка на всякий случай. хуже может будет только в многопоточном приложении, но тут явно не тот случай.

Comment: `words[i].length() >0` - `words[i].empty()`. Но даже если и не проверять, то обращение к индексу по размеру строки возвращает '\0', так что не будет исключений (пруф - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at, ну кроме доисторических компиляторов). А static тут излишен. Без него компилятор сделает куда лучше код. Но вот const тут явно был бы к месту.

Comment: Открываем вашу ссылку и читаем первую же строку. Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed. If pos > size(), the behavior is undefined. Я считаю, лучше сделать лишнюю проверку, чем наступить на UB и мучаться потом с отладкой. Свежие стандартны хорошо, но к сожалению не все проекты делаются на последних версиях компиляторов. length() и size() (по-сути алиасы одного и того же кода) empty() это size()==0 в реализации MS VS по крайней  мере. оба возвращают this->_Get_data()._Mysize.

Comment: Специально интереса ради проверил, при обращении к не инициализированной строке дальше ноля или за пределы size() компилятор VS генерирует ассерт, на GCC не пробовал.

Comment: если у Вас строка не инициализированна - тут может быть все что угодно (хотя я бы хотел увидеть, как именно это сделано). Обращение к строке по индексу равному размеру строки для чтения - законно. Проверил в студии - нет исключений.  А вот дальше за пределами - тут конечно может быть все что угодно

Comment: я не призываю обращаться по `s[s.size()]`. Все изначально было в том, что я призываю использовать empty(),  а Вы `lenght() == 0`. Но Вы решили вывернуть, мол я призываю не делать проверок вообще (что не есть таковым).

Answer (score 3):

Допустим, что std::string s - это строка. Первая буква слова - это `s[0]`. Конечно, перед этим лучше проверить, а вообще в строке есть хотя бы один символ - `if (`[!s.empty()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty)`) { /*строка не пустая*/ }`

Теперь самое сложное - проверить, что буква согласная. тут все очень просто - нужно на каждую возможную букву проверить.

```
char c = s[0];
if (c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == 'd'....) {
  // делаем что то полезное
}
```

ну и остальные согласные символы добавляете аналогично. Осталось соединить все это аккуратно и будет как нужно.

Но так как согласных больше, можно проверять на гласные и инвертировать условие

```
char c = s[0];
if (c != 'a' && c != 'i' && c != 'o'....) {
  // делаем что то полезное
}
```

Comment: может лучше `switch` и `toupper`?

Comment: а смысл? писать больше, эффективности не добавит. Если уж хочется "скорости", тогда я бы завел массив на 26 булей и просто проверял в нем по `consonant[c-'a']`

Comment: а вы думаете 30 условий в коде займет меньше памяти чем поиск литерала по одному массиву из 30 значений?

Comment: Вам шашечки или ехать?

Comment: вы код для С/С++ предлагаете или для 1С, где иногда другого варианта кроме как сделать 200 если просто нет. зачем учить людей делать неправильно в азах.

Comment: У нас с++ в тегах, а не 1с. И даже там есть десятки способов сделать по другому.